# syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am trying to add an image to my script but i keep getting the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/paidtosi/public_html/pages/shoutbox/index.php on line 59

this is line 59:

```
$image24 = "<img src="pulpit.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228">"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Really? The syntax highlighting doesn't show you the error?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean please. Thanks

Comment: Your quotes, either your escape them $image24 = "<img src=\"pulpit.jpg\"..." or you use singe quotes:  $image24 = '<img src="pulpit.jpg"';

Comment: The syntax highlighting wasn't there in the original post, because the question was not tagged with the php tag.

Answer (score 1):

To use double quotes inside double quoted strings, you have to escape them using `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$image24 = '<img src="pulpit.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228">';
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much! Cant believe i forgot the ; on the end of the line!

Comment: The missing semicolon was not the cause of the error message.

Comment: @Lewis It was a combo of the semicolon and quoting, but glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line with this:

```
  $image24 = '<img src="pulpit.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228">';
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to escape the double quotes inside the double quotes ? Or use single quotes for the whole string while keeping double quotes as is.